How can I change the color of horizontal underline on active brackets in VS Code?
Can you please help me to color the horizontal underline on active brackets color vscode (like in the photo)?

I can change the color for the vertical line with: "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground1": "#aac524";
I am using the Atom One Dark theme.




I have no extensions installed;
I have tried with these two in settings.json ("editorBracketMatch.border": "#aac524",
"editorBracketMatch.background": "#aac524") and it didn't work.

CURRENT Configuration:
  `"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "[Atom One Dark]": {
  "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground1": "#aac524",
  "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground2": "#793415",
  "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground3": "#FF75B5",
  "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground4": "#45A9F9",
  "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground5": "#B084EB",
  "editorIndentGuide.activeBackground6": "#E6E6E6",
  "editorBracketPairGuide.background1": "#aac524",
  "editorBracketPairGuide.background2": "#FF75B5",
  "editorBracketPairGuide.background3": "#45A9F9",
  "editorBracketPairGuide.background4": "#B084EB",
  "editorBracketPairGuide.background5": "#E6E6E6",
  "editorBracketPairGuide.background6": "#19f9d8",
  "editorBracketPairGuide.activeBackground1": "#FFB86C",
  "editorBracketPairGuide.activeBackground2": "#d4151580",
  "editorBracketPairGuide.activeBackground3": "#45A9F9",
  "editorBracketPairGuide.activeBackground4": "#B084EB",
  "editorBracketPairGuide.activeBackground5": "#E6E6E6",
  "editorBracketPairGuide.activeBackground6": "#19f9d8",
  "editorBracketHighlight.foreground1": "#ff0000",
  "editorBracketHighlight.foreground2": "#ff0000",
  "editorBracketHighlight.foreground3": "#ff0000",
  "editorBracketHighlight.foreground4": "#ff0000",
  "editorBracketHighlight.foreground5": "#ff0000",
  "editorBracketHighlight.foreground6": "#ff0000",
  }}` 


Please add your configuration settings as text within the question rather than a screenshot of them. This would allow anyone else to copy your settings to their VS Code (if they so wished)

" I just want the active line to be highlighted with a colored underline."  This can't be done (an extension can do this).  You can add a border - on ALL sides - of the active line with  "editor.lineHighlightBorder": "#f00",.

It should just be editorBracketPairGuide.activeBackground# and editorBracketPairGuide.background# (for non-active pair). For the record, editor indent guides are not the same as bracket pair guides.

Thank you @starball ! I have them already, it still doesn't work. As you mentioned, I think what I need has nothing to do with brackets. I just want the active line to be highlighted with a colored underline.
